# haproxy failover active-passive

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, failover, active-passive

i want to setup haproxy to switch to passive s2 after s1 fails but not to back to s1 when it gets healthy. i mean when switches to s2 if the s1 gets available, haproxy still send requests to s2 and s1 work as passive until failure of s1.
 haproxy configuration :

```
listen  http_web 192.168.1.3:80   
mode http
balance roundrobin
option httpchk
option forwardfor

    server server1 192.168.1.1:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 check backup
    server server2 192.168.1.2:80 weight 1 maxconn 512 check backup
```

i set backup for both servers but when s1 fails haproxy send requests to s2 but when s1 gets back available it sends requests to s1 again.

Answer (score 0):

round robin balancing mode, means that both servers will get requests one by one.

If you want persistence, you should use **source** method or add cookies.

Otherwise, if you don't need a load balacing feature and just active passive solution. You can use keepalived service ;)